# Create unique ID for SQL Server VIew

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Is it possible to create an ID column for a grouped view? For instance I'm trying to also create a unique clustered index for the view, hence I need a unique column that does not contain duplicates.

Much Appreciated!!

Jonathan

Comment: You can create a unique index on an indexed view, yes, but I don't see how you could "enforce" that uniqueness in the view.  If that made sense...

Comment: You cannot index views with union or row_number.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to re-address my question to: "What is the proper procedure of creating a grouped view with clustered index?" Unique ID is not the key here, main reason is I've created this grouped view but extremely slow and trying to boost some performances. Thanks for any advice to my rookie question!

Comment: You should probably re-ask. This question will lead nowhere. It is too unspecific and unclear.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'out-of-the-box' solution however you can workaround by using `ROW_NUMBER` over columns that do not have unique records.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1, Col2), Col1, Col2, ... FROM 
   (SELECT X AS Col1 FROM [Table] 
   UNION ALL SELECT Y AS Col2 FROM [Table2])
```